# Rails 5 gem 'delayed_job_active_record' uninitialized constant Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I have two jobs to run in Production one is always working fine, but other gets stuck sometimes with error

```
 uninitialized constant AppointmentReminderJob\nDid you mean? 
 AppointmentLog\n/Path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport- 
 5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in
```

Started delayed job on Production via `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart`

In `application.rb`  set  `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job`

File name `appointment_reminder_job.rb`

```
class AppointmentReminderJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(appointment, clinic)
     # My code here
  end
end
```

Setting Job

```
AppointmentReminderJob.set(wait_until: Appointment::TIME_LIMIT).perform_later(@appointment, @clinic)
```

**Note:** Am not getting this error always but sometimes.

Comment: It seems that the class `AppointmentReminderJob` is not being loaded by Rails. What are the file paths for the two jobs classes in your Rails project? Did you restart the delayed job process after making changes to those classes?

Comment: @pedrosfdcarneiro job files are in the same directory. If loading was the issue it should have been with other jobs too or it should occur every time. Am getting this issue seldom, and this is on happening on Production, can't restart server manually everytime.